# NoClassDefFoundError: org/datanucleus/enhancement/Detachable

Tags: java, log4j, noclassdeffounderror, datanucleus

I'm getting this error when running a server in ant:

```
NoClassDefFoundError: org/datanucleus/enhancement/Detachable
```

I looked for the PersistentCapable classes and all of them are detachable. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: add the jar to the classpath?

Comment: if the code is web, you need to add library in libs

Comment: @ScaryWombat everything has been added to the classpath (the lib folder). It works in Linux but not in W10 nor Mac...